# How to set up range of paging for a specific category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, paging

I would need to limit the number of products displayed on a page **for only a certain category** in Magento.

For example, the category pencils show 10 products per page while category pens show 20 products per page.

In other words, how to rewrite the paging configuration of Magento for a category ?

Comment: Can you show the code ,what you have written so far?

Comment: Sorry, no code... :(

Answer (score 1):

You Can Visit App->design->fronted->default->theamName->page->template->html in HTML Folder or open List.phtml file on top of file you find category id and then apply number of product show on using IF else Condication .

Hope This Help You

Thainks

Comment: Sorry, try to explain better... What I'm looking for is the ability to set the default pagination of a category. Overwriting the default system configuration (for all category) set in the backend (admin > system > configuration > catalog ... )